# Отображение конфигурации битов в байте

Tags: c++

Изучаю побитовые операции по книге Шилдта "C++ руководство для начинающих", где он приводит пример использования побитового `&` для отображения битового состава числа (ввод числа пользователем я сам добавил):

```
int main()
{
    int j = 0,
        t = 0;

    cin >> j;
    for (t = 128; t > 0; t/2)
    {
        if(j & t) cout << "1";
        else cout << "0";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Мне эта программа показалась непонятной, и я решил попробовать запустить ее, чтобы разобрать по косточкам, но вместо ожидаемого побитового вывода я получил бесконечно выводимые со скоростью света единички. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Вы операцию не задали, `t = t/2` или `t/=2` вместо `t/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо этого

```
for (t = 128; t > 0; t/2)
```

вот это (иначе вы **не меняете** значение `t`):

```
for (t = 128; t > 0; t/=2)
```